# Архаичное слово "пореть"

Tags: значения, склонение

Встретил поговорку в словаре Даля «Пословицы русского народа»: `Старики хилеют, молодые пореют.`

В толковом же словаре Даля есть толкование глаголу "Пореть":
`ПОРЕТЬ, см. парить, пора.`

Так что же означает это слово, корректно ли его так приводить и откуда вообще идут его корни?

Comment: что значит "корректно ли его так приводить"? это слово устарело до той степени, что вас просто не поймут.

Comment: отличное слово, жаль вышло из употребления, хотя звучит вполне современно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Пореют (пореть)*** -- устаревшее слово. Оно означает ***взрослеть, мужать, крепчать, входить в пору***. Этимологически слово ***пореть*** берет свое начало от слова ***переть*** в значении давить. Напор, отпор. ***Порый*** – в старину здоровый, крепкий.

Подробнее: https://obrazovaka.ru/proverochnoe-slovo/pora.html#ixzz5XORsVtl3